# "Repair" procedure for broken Asus Eee power adaptor

Tags: power-supply

I have an Asus Eee PC 901 with a broken power supply. Doing some Internet search, I found a [blog response](http://loranablog.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/the-cheap-power-adapter-of-asus-eeepc/) stating that these power supplies can be repaired by "smacking them on a desk /floor / even surface".

I would like a more detailed description of this "repair" procedure (what side goes up/down, how hard to smack, etc.).

Comment: If I had the reputation, I'd tag this "percussive-maintenance".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just buy a replacement, they are not expensive and you will be guaranteed of getting a working adapter.

Whilst hitting some electronic devices can work, it should never be recommended.

Comment: You're probably right :-) Actually I've still got warranty, so I can get a replacement for free. I'm just too lazy to drive the 15km to the store, and 15km back...

Answer (score 3):

This is coincidence that his power adapter worked afterwards *again*. A power adapter is a technical device, and as all technical devices they can fail in so many different ways that I can't even think of all.

Maybe his just had a loose contact which reseated itself during the *procedure*. Smacking/punching/throwing devices is *not* a repair procedure, it's hit or miss.